# Change detection not happening with async await

Tags: angular, zone.js

1.showing a loader until API resolvers
2. After a getting API response, setting the loader flag to false, and trying to read the div inside flag
3. Flag value is updated but dom is not refreshed, so i dont have reference to a div inside a if condition

Why dom is not refreshed here..

Code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-validation-angular-15-zgnf3n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: You really should include the code in question here instead of just a link to an external site. Having the stackblitz example is an excellent way to provide a working example, but shouldn't be the bulk of your question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the code in question isn't included on SO, but rather a link to StackBlitz

Answer (score 0):

A constructor shouldn't have async code in it. There are ways to get it to work, but Angular provides various lifecycle events that should be utilized instead.

`ngAfterViewInit` would be my recommendation here as follows:

```
{{ !showLoader }}
<ng-container *ngIf="!showLoader ? widget : loaderMsg"></ng-container>
<div #widget></div>

<ng-template #loaderMsg> Loading... </ng-template>
```

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {
    AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  showLoader = true;
  @ViewChild('widget', { static: false }) widget: ElementRef;
  API_KEY = '{{YOUR_API_KEY}}';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  async ngAfterViewInit(): Promise<any> {
    await this.loadDashboard();
  }

  async loadDashboard() {
    this.showLoader = true;
    const isInitalDataFetched: any = await this.getValue().catch(() => {
      return false;
    });
    console.log('test', isInitalDataFetched);
    if (isInitalDataFetched) {
    } else {
      this.showLoader = false;
      // this.cdr.detectChanges();
      console.log(this.widget);
    }
    console.log('test');
    console.log(this.widget);
  }

  getValue() {
    return this.httpClient
      .get(
        `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=${this.API_KEY}`
      )
      .toPromise();
  }
}
```

The [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#using-aftercontent-hooks) on `AfterContent` hooks explain that content 'children' aren't available until one of these hooks.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-validation-angular-15-idohcy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: Even with oninit also it wont have reference to widget. if we check on console , it shows undefined.

Comment: Please update your question to 1. Include your code. 2. Clearly state a question. Based on the title, you are asking about async/await. With the code in Stackblitz, your code isn't utilizing async/await all the way through as you can't await a function call in the constructor.